# How to pass a generic Type for an Ng-Component from the HTML template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

Considering I have a generic Component and want to define its Type by the invocation from the HTML-Template depending on a passed attribute (in this case "plotTab). How can I do this?

foo.component.ts:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-selector',
  templateUrl: './my-selector.html',
  providers: [
    {provide: BaseService, useClass: A_Service},
    {provide: BaseService, useClass: B_Service}   
  ]
})
export class UsageTableBaseComponent<T>{
 // ...
}
```

Invoking HTML-template snippet:

```html
<!-- some HTML stuff -->
  <my-selector *ngIf="
    [plots]="plots"      
    [subtable]="'A'"
  </my-selector>
<!-- some HTML stuff -->
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate what the purpose is? What do you wish to accomplish by different types? Do you render different elements based on the type?

Comment: Sure. Ive got three subtables. Depending on the corresponding table i want to list different fields of different classes. i.e. the user clicks "Harvest" I want to display field from the Harvest class. If he clicks Fertilization I want to do the same but for Fertilization class.

Comment: From what I understand, you should be able to do it with `<ng-content>` in the child component.

Comment: May you share your idea a little more precide please? I am kinda new with ng.

Comment: [This](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/) would be a good starting point.